# Pandoc - How to modify CSL <citation /> to show citation-label in text?

Tags: bibliographies, citing, pandoc

I'm currently using [this Project from Github](https://github.com/tompollard/phd_thesis_markdown) to write my Bachelor Thesis using Markdown and Pandoc.
Since my university has some guidelines to follow regarding Styling, I need to modify the `.cls` to use the `label` of my reference, instead of the `author` inline as reference.

What I expect as result is:
Inline:

```
This is a text. [EXA1]
```

and in my References:

```
[EXA1] : This is a Test. Accessed: ...
```

I'm pretty new to LaTex.

I tried **2 different approaches**.

Can someone please tell me what I'm missing and which approach I should use?

Thank in advance!

**1. Approach**

If I'm right, according to the CSL 1.0.1 Specification `citation-label` variable should work for me.

```xml
    <macro name="short">
      <text variable="citation-label"/>
    </macro>
    <citation et-al-min="6" et-al-use-first="1" et-al-subsequent-min="3" et-al-subsequent-use-first="1" disambiguate-add-year-suffix="true" disambiguate-add-names="true" disambiguate-add-givenname="true" collapse="year" givenname-disambiguation-rule="primary-name">
      <layout prefix="[" suffix="]" delimiter="; ">
        <text macro="short"/>
      </layout>
    </citation>
    <bibliography hanging-indent="true" et-al-min="8" et-al-use-first="6" entry-spacing="0" line-spacing="2">
      <layout>
        <text macro="short"/>
        <text macro="author"/>
        <text macro="issued" suffix=":"/>
        <text macro="title" suffix="." prefix=" "/>
        <text macro="container" prefix=" "/>
        <text macro="locators"/>
        <text macro="access" prefix=" "/>
      </layout>
    </bibliography>
```

But the resulting `pdf` only shows empty brackets `[]`.

**2. Approach**
I also tried to add another `key` to my reference definition and use this in my `.cls` file:

```xml
    @MISC{EXA1,
      cit-label = {EXA1},
      author = {Test, Thomas},
      title = {This is an example},
      month = Januar,
      year = {2021},
      howpublished={\url{https://example.com}}
    }

    <macro name="short">
      <text variable="cit-label"/>
    </macro>
    <citation et-al-min="6" et-al-use-first="1" et-al-subsequent-min="3" et-al-subsequent-use-first="1" disambiguate-add-year-suffix="true" disambiguate-add-names="true" disambiguate-add-givenname="true" collapse="year" givenname-disambiguation-rule="primary-name">
      <layout prefix="[" suffix="]" delimiter="; ">
        <text macro="short"/>
      </layout>
    </citation>
    <bibliography hanging-indent="true" et-al-min="8" et-al-use-first="6" entry-spacing="0" line-spacing="2">
      <layout>
        <text macro="short"/>
        <text macro="author"/>
        <text macro="issued" suffix=":"/>
        <text macro="title" suffix="." prefix=" "/>
        <text macro="container" prefix=" "/>
        <text macro="locators"/>
        <text macro="access" prefix=" "/>
      </layout>
    </bibliography>
```

This results in Empty Brackets as well.

Comment: CSL is the "un-LaTeX-y" bit of the pandoc world, so this question is borderline off-topic here and you probably won't find a lot of people able to help here anyway. The Zotero forum (https://forums.zotero.org/) is usually pretty quick to offer help with CSL files (see also https://www.zotero.org/support/dev/citation_styles/style_editing_step-by-step).

Comment: Oh @moewe I didn't know about that. Thank you for your explanations and the links.

Comment: See also https://github.com/citation-style-language/styles/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#asking-for-help and https://github.com/citation-style-language/styles/blob/master/REQUESTING.md#requesting-csl-styles